# how to use $.ajax() in anywhere

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

My file is in D drive

D:/item/1.js

I do not use xampp or wamp

It does not work

```
function request($i){
$url = "item/"+$i+".js";
$.ajax({
crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  type: 'post', 
  url: $url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(datax){
   //return data;
   data = datax;
  },
  error: function(){
   //return error();
   data = error();
  }
});

}
```

I want to work from anywhere

For example :

file:///c:/document/item/1.js
 , flash memory
 , and ....

I can not use .load() because I get to Json

Thanks

Comment: Some browsers completely block all ajax requests to files on the filesystem. You'll have to look at your browser in particular and modify the security settings to allow it.

Comment: If you're doing this for your local file system, you will have security issues. As Kevin mentioned, most browsers block ajax requests, especially to the file system. You can try using HTML 5 file system features to access files. Here is a tutorial on using it, [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)